# How to read variables from .SAV files in batch

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have set a variable in a .SAV file, is there anyway to make a batch file to read that variable?

The Varible I set in there was, set d=200 So in a batch file can I read it using %'s ?

like if %d%==200 goto Example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 200>file
set /p var=<file
echo %var%
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is to set varialbes within the batch file to set from the file. What you can do is instead of having the command "set d=200" within the batch file, type "d=200". With the command I will preview, you can use many many different variables. For example, within that 1 file, you can have the first line say "d=200" (you don't need quotes) and on the next line, have "cat=100" and you can set both within the batch file.

The following command will allow you to set all variables from the variables in the file:

```
for /f %%A in ('type [path here].sav') do set %%A
```

This will set all variables from %%a (temp) to the variables from the file (d=200 from the .sav file will now be 200 in the batch file). This tool is really useful if you want to save and load information for a game for example.